# phpMyAdmin import issue for a table

Tags: php, mysql

i made a database in MySQL. In that database i want to import a table while i importing a table after some time it gave that error message
This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/import might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

Can anyone give me an accurate solution.

i had updated the `max_execution_time` , `upload_max_filesize` , `post_max_size` and `max_input_time` but again receiving this error .